# Do git merges for remote machine locally and with a GUI

Tags: linux, windows, git, merge

So I have a remote Centos server running a small app and I have a git repo set up on that machine. To date, I've been running git from that centos server via ssh terminal, including doing some merging via `mergetool`, specifically `vimdiff`. This is...okay. Not great. A terminal editor split into four panes is vaguely terrifying.

What I would like to do is handle the merges via a Windows machine and some friendly GUI based merge tool, but I *don't* want to clone the repo to the windows machine. I want the windows machine to perform the merge on the Centos machines files directly.

I suspect this is possible, but I'm not having much luck with google. A link to instructions would be fine.

Any help?

Comment: Not without cloning, no

Comment: Have you tried mounting the server's file system from Windows using NFS or Samba?

Comment: Samba might be a good idea. thanks.